# Google Maps API: Marker link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have been playing around with the Google Maps API and managed to do what I wanted. Basically I'm creating a custom map using some specific parameters from the HTML. The map works well and the marker pops at the correct location, however I have two small issues which I am not able to fix:

1. The marker's link doesn't work - I get the following error message in my log: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_*e3*' of undefined
2. When the page loads the map is set on the default location first, then it updates with the specific location when the function is run. Is there anyway I can make it load with the correct location at once?

Here is the HTML code with the specific parameters:

```
<div id="map" data-map-address="120-124 Curtain Road, London, EC2A 3SQ" data-map-link="http://my-destination-link.com"></div>
```

And here is the JavaScript I use to generate the map:

```
var map,
    geocoder,
    mapElem = document.getElementById('map'),
    mapHolder = $('#map'),
    mapAddress = mapHolder.attr("data-map-address"),
    mapUrl = mapHolder.attr("data-map-link"),
    image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://my-marker-link.com/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(123, 123),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(11, 96));

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51121, -0.11982),
        mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': mapAddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                url: mapUrl,
                title: 'Click here to emlarge the map',
                icon: image
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeAddress);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = marker.url;
});
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to solve these two issues. I looked online and tried the workarounds I found, but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a missing semicolon after `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }` Not sure if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, what do you mean? That is part of an object. So it does not need a semicolon.

Comment: @putvande I just ran a JSHint on it and it complained! As I said, not sure if it had anything to do with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: I would put the `codeAddress()` inside your initialize for the onload bit. Don't set a center yet in the initialize but wait for the `codeAddress()` to find and set the location.

2: You get that error because you are putting the eventlistener for your marker in the wrong place. Out there it does not know what the variable `marker` is. You need to place it where your marker is created (inside your `codeAddress()` function.

```
var map,
    geocoder,
    mapElem = document.getElementById('map'),
    mapHolder = $('#map'),
    mapAddress = mapHolder.attr("data-map-address"),
    mapUrl = mapHolder.attr("data-map-link"),
    image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://my-marker-link.com/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(123, 123),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(11, 96));

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);

    codeAddress();
}

function codeAddress() {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': mapAddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                url: mapUrl,
                title: 'Click here to emlarge the map',
                icon: image
            });

            // Add your event listener 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                window.location.href = marker.url;
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Awesome, the map is now showing with the correct location on page load. However the link still doesn't work for me, I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined. I tried to define the variable globally but then I get the same error as before.

Comment: Did you put it in the position inside the code where I have it in my answer?

Comment: Yes I copied your code. I have tried again just now and it's working perfectly well, that must have been a cache issue earlier on. Thanks for your help - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why the link is failing but to make the map load at the correct location off-the-bat you're going to have to geocode the location first and once you get a response from the maps api you can then build your map with the correct starting position.

```
var map,
geocoder,
mapElem = document.getElementById('map'),
    mapHolder = $('#map'),
    mapAddress = mapHolder.attr("data-map-address"),
    mapUrl = mapHolder.attr("data-map-link"),
    image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://my-marker-link.com/marker.png',
    new google.maps.Size(123, 123),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(11, 96));

function initialize(geoLocation) {
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: geoLocation,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElem, mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': mapAddress
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            initialize(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                url: mapUrl,
                title: 'Click here to enlarge the map',
                icon: image
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                window.location.href = marker.url;
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
//Call codeAddress to initialize the geocoding.  When that returns it will initialize the map with the geocode location
codeAddress();
```